# How to use position in CSS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<table id="tab">
    <tr><td class="here">dgd</td><td class="here">dfg</td></tr>
    <tr><td class="here">fgf</td><td class="here">sg4</td></tr>
</table>


<table id="new">
    <tr><td id="al">sss</td></tr>
</table>

#tab td {
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

#new td {
    padding: 5px;
    height: 40px;
      border: solid 1px green;
    background-color: green;
}

#new {
    display: none;
}

$(".here").click(function(){
   $("#new").show();
})

    $("#al").click(function(){
       alert('ok');
    })
```

LIVE: http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnK/

How can i modify this example for add position in jQuery? I would like - if i click on .here then **table id = new** should show me on this clicked TD. Additionally if i clicked outside **table id = new** then this should hide.

How can i make it?

Comment: What are you trying to do?  Make the color of the cell change when it is clicked?  Because there's an easier way to do that.

Comment: no color. i would like show hide table. This is in example. Please use jsfiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to be like this?

http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnK/6/

Comment: yes, very thanks :) but could you add also if i clicked outside green box, then this green box is hidden?

Answer (score 1):

You want an event handler on the whole page, which will respond to clicks on it, but not on clicks within certain areas.

Use `event.stopPropogation()` to prevent the page from responding to certain areas:

```
$('.item').click(function(event){
    $('#context').show();
    event.stopPropogation();
});
$('body').click(function(){
    $('#context').hide();
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MvsG4/)

Answer (score 1):

If you're saying that the green box should be moved to the same position as the clicked cell (via absolute positioning, as compared to appending it as a child of the clicked cell) then you could try something like this:

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    var $el = $(e.target);
    if ($el.hasClass("here")) {
        $("#new").css({'left': e.target.offsetLeft,
                       'top': e.target.offsetTop}).show();
    } else {
        $("#new").hide();
    }
});
```

Which processes clicks on the document. If the click is in one of the ".here" cells it moves the green box, otherwise it hides it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HTHnK/16/

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking to move text from the source cell to the new table cell?

http://jsfiddle.net/dnrar/